# CSS Custom Fonts In Construct 2

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, construct-2

Okay, so I have been developing utilizing Construct 2. I installed a custom font, and it works great locally. However, when I try to upload and visit on my phone, the font doesn't render.

Eventually after scanning forums, I found that I can use an event sheet and call the "**SET WEB FONT FACE**". Next I uploaded the TTF and WOFF files, and finally added CSS... but here's the catch.... The font will not render until I flip the phone sideways. Any suggestions or has anyone else experienced this with custom fonts in construct 2? I can post a link if need be. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured this one out on my own. If anyone else runs into this situation, make sure to set the web font actions BEFORE runtime is triggered.